# Is there a significance to Valkyrja's powerset?

Tags: character-analysis, april-daniels, nemesis-series

In April Daniels's [Nemesis series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/190950-nemesis), the character Valkyrja/Karen has an unusual, very specific array of powers:

> I can sense where things that open the way are...  Also people who are about to die, and any serious violence within a hundred miles. Plus ravens, swans, horses, and alcohol. Technically, it's not a hundred miles, it's twenty-seven leagues.
> <sub>Karen, from Chapter Nine of *Sovereign*</sub>

Karen gains powers when Valkyrja, her mother, dies. Karen also gains Valkyrja's memories, and initially feels as if her mother is try to take over Karen's mind. By the end of  *Sovereigm* Karen has embraced the name and legacy of Valkyrja, and Valkyrja's personality has almost completely taken over. Karen/Valkyrja then leaves to have her own child to secure the legacy of the powers.

Edit: Somehow I forgot to mention that Valkyrja has wings that allow her to fly. Karen's wings grow in overnight, and her memories and powers follow close after.

<sub>If any of that was confusing, please tell me and I'll try to make it more clear</sub>

The variety of Valkyrja's powers seems random to me. Her character is Old-Norse flavored, and some of the power (ravens, alchohol) seem to have some connection to Norse mythology. But some of the others seem completely random, such as “things that open the way”. Is there some connection between this disparate powers? Do the specific items listed have a deeper significance? For that matter, does the number 27 mean anything important? Or the manner in which the powers pass on?

Is there a significance to Valkyrja's powerset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read this series, but it's clear at a glance that the name Valkyrja is related to the famous [valkyries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie), the warrior women of Norse mythology best known for choosing fallen warriors in the field of battle and bringing them to Valhalla. A quick look on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie) reveals that "valkyrja" is actually the original Old Norse name, and also notes connections with ravens, swans, horses, and alcohol:

> In Norse mythology, a valkyrie ([...] from Old Norse valkyrja "chooser of the slain") is one of a host of female figures who choose those who may die in battle and those who may live. Selecting among half of those who die in battle (the other half go to the goddess Freyja's afterlife field Fólkvangr), the valkyries take their chosen to the afterlife hall of the slain, Valhalla, ruled over by the god Odin. There, the deceased warriors become einherjar (Old Norse "single (or once) fighters"). When the einherjar are not preparing for the events of Ragnarök, the valkyries bear them mead. Valkyries also appear as lovers of heroes and other mortals, where they are sometimes described as the daughters of royalty, sometimes accompanied by ravens and sometimes connected to swans or horses.

[Mythology.net](https://mythology.net/norse/norse-creatures/valkyrie/) confirms these connections:

> The Valkyries’ nobility is reflected in their appearance. They have lily-white skin and statuesque figures. Their hair can be gold as the sunlight or black as the night. During times of peace, these women wear elegant costumes made from swan or raven feathers, but when war draws near, they don their armor: gracefully carved helmets and shields and chain mail corsets. They might continue wearing a feather cape, or, according to some stories, they might sprout wings of their own to help them soar above the battlefields. [...]
>
> First and foremost, the Valkyries influenced the fate of warriors and battles (with Odin’s approval, of course). Some stories describe them working at magical looms—with intestines for threads, heads for weights, and swords and arrows for beaters—where they wove the destiny of each fighter into a tapestry that would determine the outcome of the whole battle. Other stories describe them riding horses through the clouds above an active battle. [...]
>
> Finally, the Valkyrie are well-known for serving and brewing mead. Not only is their mead delicious, it has magical properties that can make men stronger, improve their memory, or heal their wounds.

Finally, the [significant numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Norse_mythology) in old Norse culture all seem to be powers of 3:

> The numbers three and nine are significant numbers in Norse mythology and paganism. Both numbers (and multiplications thereof) appear throughout surviving attestations of Norse paganism, in both mythology and cultic practice. While the number three appears significant in many cultures, Norse mythology appears to put special emphasis on the number nine. Along with the number 27, both numbers also figure into the lunar Germanic calendar.
>
> <sub>-- Wikipedia, cited to Rudolf Simek's *Dictionary of Northern Mythology*</sub>

Now almost all the powers of Valkyrja make sense in terms of what she is, a valkyrie (valkyrja) from Norse mythology:

- Sensing people who are about to die. That makes sense since the whole purpose of a valkyrie is to find dying warriors and choose which ones should be taken to Valhalla.
- Sensing serious violence. That again makes sense: valkyries are essentially spirits of the battlefield.
- Ravens, swans, and horses. All of these have some kind of thematic connection to valkyries, as noted above: they may wear the feathers of ravens or swans, and they may ride horses or have (like their boss Odin) raven companions.
- Alcohol. That again makes sense since valkyries were known for the mead they made and served in Valhalla. (Ties into the stereotype of Viking men spending all their time either fighting or drinking! The battles were worthwhile for them if it meant they had a chance to spend eternity drinking and surrounded by beautiful women.)
- Twenty-seven leagues. That's eighty-one miles, close enough to a hundred, assuming we go by the standard definition of a [league](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_(unit)) as three miles, and twenty-seven was considered a significant number in the culture that produced the valkyrie stories.
- Wings. That again makes sense since valkyries are meant to *fly* over battlefields.

The only thing I can't figure out is "things that open the way", and in fact I'm not really sure what that *means*. Like doors and gates? In that case, maybe it could be a reference to the doors and gates of [Valhalla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valhalla), meant to be opened at Ragnarök to let the warriors out. (You can read a translated version of the [Grímnismál](http://www.voluspa.org/grimnismal21-25.htm) to see a description of Valhalla with its gate Valgrind and many doors.)